# Why does it repeat so many times?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

Here is the code, it basically uses a win32com instance and gets the attribute and sets the attribute.
More methods will be added to this class later.

```
import win32com.client

class WORD(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.word = win32com.client.Dispatch("Word.Application")

    def __getattr__(self, val):
        try:
            print(1)            
            attr = getattr(self.word, val)
        except:
            print(2)
            attr = super().__getattr__(val)
        return attr

    def __setattr__(self, attr, val):
        try:
            print(3)
            setattr(self.word, attr, val)
        except:
            print(4)
            super().__setattr__(attr, val)    


app = WORD()
```

It outputs 2 for 635 times and a 4 at the end. Why? Thank you.

```
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
.
.
.
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's follow what happens here:

```py
    def __init__(self):
        self.word = win32com.client.Dispatch("Word.Application")
```

`self.word = ...` executes `setattr(self, ...)` which tries to do `getattr(self.word, ...)`, which leads to `getattr(self, 'word')`, which tries to do `getattr(self.word, 'word')`, which ends up in a recursive loop. Once [Python's recursion limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323001/what-is-the-maximum-recursion-depth-in-python-and-how-to-increase-it) is reached, a `RecursionError` is thrown. Your `try...except` blocks ignore this exception and eventually end  the cycle by calling the corresponding methods on `super()`.

A simple way to work around this and get the functionality that I am guessing you're after, is to change the initialiser as follows:

```py
    def __init__(self):
        super().__setattr__('word', win32com.client.Dispatch("Word.Application"))
```

This bypasses your custom `__setattr__` implementation for the property `word` so that this property is available inside those methods, avoiding recursion.

Comment: Another condemnation of blanket except clauses! This is exactly why they're discouraged.